# Does Google charge streaming fee when import Firebase Google Analytic data to BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I know that when Google Firebase project link to BigQuery, user has to pay for storage fee and Queries fee as it documents in [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing)
But I wonder if Google also charges streaming inserts fee in this case ? Is it just an "import/export" case (without fee) or is it really a streaming action when migrate data from Firebase Analytics to BigQuery then user has to pay for this also?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 1):

As noted:

- BigQuery has a free storage tier.
- BigQuery has a free queries tier.
- BigQuery doesn't have a free streaming tier.

So the current answer is: When exporting Analytics for Firebase to BigQuery, you can do most for free (up to certain limits), except the streaming.